# I’m not sure if this is correct

Tags: phrase-usage

“and don’t get me started on how adorable that picture on the back cover is”

while it seems correct, but it kinda itches me a little bit. it doesn’t sound right somehow. or is there a better way to say it?

Comment: Sounds exactly as it should.
Can you be more specific to the part that "doesn't sound right somehow" ?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct.

"Don't get me started on something" means "Don't make me start talking about it (because I have so much to say). If I start, it may be difficult to stop me."

If this is not what makes you think there is something wrong with the sentence, perhaps you have doubts about the preposition "on" before "the back cover." It is correct too. We say "in the picture" but "on the cover."

Comment: thank you sm!! that helps a lot!

Answer (score -1):

The phrase "don’t get me started on ..." is more usually used for something that irritates you, such as

> Don't get me started on Brexit.

or when you don't want someone *else* to start talking about a topic they *like* but will probably bore everybody.

> Don't get him started on his hobby.

It's not a very good usage in this case: how much would you have to say about a photograph? I suggest something like this:

> I can't tell you how much I adore that picture.